# How can I improve on Readable stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have such code that is working perfectly below. The thing is that all the questions regarding Readable is very old so I wanted to ask if am I missing something? Is there a better way to read IncomingMessage?

I tried `doc.on('data', chunk => {})` but didn't work. Also I still don't quite understand how it knows when the read ends - just by `.read()` becoming null?

This is the endpoint I'm using to get this stream: https://gotenberg.dev/docs/get-started/live-demo if someone wants to play around.

P.S. and yes, I wrapped it in Promise so I can use it as async-await function :)

```
async function generateBufferFromIncomingMessage(doc) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = []

    doc.on('readable', (chunk) => {
      // console.log('readable')
      while (null !== (chunk = doc.read())){
        chunks.push(chunk)
      }
    })

    doc.on('end', () => {
      // console.log('end')
      const result = Buffer.concat(chunks)
      resolve(result)
    })

    doc.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error)
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This is a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Other common uses of readable streams in Node.js applications are:

process.stdin - To read user input via stdin in a terminal application.
http.IncomingMessage - To read an incoming request's content in an HTTP server or to read the server HTTP response in an HTTP client.

first :

```
const Stream = require ( 'stream' )
const writableStream = new Stream.writable ( )
```

…and then we are on to implementing the _write :

```
writableStream._write = ( chunk , encoding , next ) => {
 console.log ( chunk . toString ( ) )
 next ( )
 }
```

Now you can pipe a read stream into it :

```
process.stdin.pipe ( writableStream )
```

this method is based on : how to use streams in Node.js by mastering backend.com
https://masteringbackend.com/posts/how-to-use-streams-in-node-js